# td and height doesn't work properly in IE

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

help me please with it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
        <table style="width: 600px;">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" style="background: #FF0;">Left<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2" height="30px" style="background: #FCC;height: 30px;">header</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Content</td>
                <td style="background: #EEE;">Right</td>
            </tr>
        </table>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Its works fine in Firefox or chrome, but IE ignoring height property and cell with text header have incorrect height. How to fix it?

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UzCRc/)

Answer (score 2):

Use an element inside the td to set height like so:

```
<div style="display:block;height:30px;">header</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure? I tested it in your Fiddle link and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, sure.. :) how it's can help, if header td have more height than I need?

Comment: You could always set height:auto; on the element, otherwise just adjust the px measurement to what it should be?

Comment: You can look at example of my page here: http://hrms.pro/test/  I can't do measurement, because left panel, content and right panel can be any height

Comment: try to look on my page in internet explorer, and you'll see difference

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, as my IE version displays it correctly.
Try enabling or disabling IE Compatibility mode

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <table style="width: 600px; height:500px">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" style="background: #FF0;">Left</td>
            <td colspan="2" height="80px" style="background: #FCC;">header</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td style="background: #EEE;">Right</td>
        </tr>
    </table>        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You remove additional rows from Left TD. If you add this, u will see, it doesn't work.. :)

Comment: no i didn't remove rows, i just removed <br> tag, becoz it should not be used in tables specially..

Comment: Well, if it was some text, not br, I should remove it?

Comment: you are misunderstanding my point, i mean to say that: we should not use <br> to indicate rows...

Answer (score 0):

height is not supported anymore with html 5 and is deprecated in html 4
Since you are using html5 I would suggest to use

style="height:30px;"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <table style="width: 600px; height:500px">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" style="background: #FF0;">Left</td>
            <td colspan="2" style="height:30px;background: #FCC;">header</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td style="background: #EEE;">Right</td>
        </tr>
    </table>        
</body>
</html>
```

Reference http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_height.asp

Answer (score -1):

I thought it'd be good to convert to DIVs and CSS:

```
<style>
    #leftPanel {
        background: #FF0;
        float: left;
        width: 135px;
    }
    #headerPanel {
        background: #FCC;
        height: 30px;
    }
    #contentPanel {
        float: left;
    }
    #rightPanel {
        background: #EEE;
        float: right;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
    }
    #containerPanel {
        width: 600px;
    }
</style>

<div id="containerPanel">
    <div id="leftPanel">
    Left<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id="headerPanel">
        header
    </div>
    <div id="contentPanel">
        Some content here...
    </div>
    <div id="rightPanel">
        Right
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to same height for all blocks. So, I can't use div in this case. May be if use javascript for calculate and set height.. But it's bad solution.